# Como converter dois valores de campos separados de um JSON em um Go map?

Tags: json, golang

Tenho um JSON parecido com esse:

```
{
    "estados":[
        {
            "sigla": "SP",
            "nome": "São Paulo"
        },
        {
            "sigla": "RJ",
            "nome": "Rio de Janeiro"
        }
    ]
}
```

Como eu podeira transformar esse `JSON` em um `map` em `Go`, onde as chaves do `map` seriam o valores do campo `sigla` e os valores seriam os valores do campo `nome`

Em Go:

```
fmt.Println(estados["SP"]) // imprime São Paulo
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta decodificar e iterar para criar o `map`.

```
func newEstadosMap() (estados map[string]string) {
    raw := []byte(`{"estados":[{"sigla":"SP","nome":"São Paulo"},{"sigla":"RJ","nome":"Rio de Janeiro"}]}`)
    dec := struct {
        Estados []struct {
            Sigla string `json:"sigla"`
            Nome  string `json:"nome"`
        } `json:"estados"`
    }{}

    if err := json.Unmarshal(raw, &dec); err != nil {
        return
    }

    estados = make(map[string]string)
    for _, estado := range dec.Estados {
        estados[estado.Sigla] = estado.Nome
    }

    return estados
}
```

Primeiro, decodificamos o `json`, para o struct `dec`. Então iteramos encima dele, do `dec.Estados` para criar o `estados`. Eu juntei tudo numa função só para ficar mais simples, mas pode quebrar isto em várias funções...

---

Então, poderia fazer:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

var Estados = newEstadosMap() // Invoca o código acima, criado o Estados assim que inicializar.

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Estados["RJ"])
}
```

Resultado:

> Rio de Janeiro